# Convert multiple line Varchar variable into one line

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Alright, I have a variable that accepts a list of zip codes. I want to be able to input these zip codes vertically, deliminated by a comma. I then want to remove these paragraph characters to transform this list into all one line of text.

Here is what I have so far, I was attempting to replace the control character used for new lines with just nothing, I don't know if this is possible, it was just my first idea:

```
SET @zip_list = 
'
44654,
15219,
15219,
15219,
' --this is my list of zip codes, place a , after every zip. 
        ---------------------------------
        print @zip_list
        SET @zip_list = replace(@zip_list,CHAR(13),'')  --Remove new line character to place zip codes all onto one line
```

Is this even possible, perhaps I am just trying to replace the wrong control character?

Comment: What you have looks like it's on the right path.  If that didn't work, try char(10) or char(10) + char(13)

Comment: You need to also replace char(10). Remember that enter is a carriage return AND a line feed. SET @ zip_list = replace(replace(@ zip_list,CHAR(13),'') , CHAR(10), '')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newlines on Windows are CR+LF. You only remove CR (`CHAR(13)`) You need to wrap it inside another `REPLACE`:

```
SET @zip_list = REPLACE(REPLACE(@zip_list,CHAR(13),''),CHAR(10),'')
```

Comment: Awesome this code works great! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is the windows OS responsible for determining what control characters are inputted when I hit enter/return? Or is it MS SQL Server? Based on your question I think you mean it's totally up to windows, but I just want to clarify.

Comment: It's the OS that determines what line break characters to use. SQL Server only runs on Windows so this is a moot point anyway.